# Is it possible to only allow people in a particular SharePoint group to be selected in a workflow?

Tags: workflow, groups

Is it possible to set up the Page Approval workflow so that only people in the Approvers group can be selected in the "Assign To" field?

Comment: Please **tag by feature or topic** and not by version or product. This helps to attract more attention to your question and keep it relevant. See [How do I use tags](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/) for general guidelines. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by first creating a copy of the **Approval - SharePoint 2010** workflow and then open **ReviewApproval_1033.xsn** Association/Initiation form in InfoPath.

Then right click on the Approvers e-mail adressess -field and select **Person/Group Picker Properties**. In the SharePoint Server tab write down the address of your site collection and then open the General-tab.

You can select a group from the **Choose from** dropdown field that you want to limit the workflow to.

Comment: I do not have InfoPath so that I cannot test it out. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sure you can set the approval group in the workflow configuration

Comment: Cheers but I can't find the option anywhere in the workflow settings. I hope I'm not overlooking something real simple haha! Basically I've set up a "Approval - Sharepoint 2010" workflow for all of the pages in a subsite. When I open the settings for that workflow (Site Actions -> View All Site Content -> Pages -> Library -> Workflow Settings), I cannot see an option that would let me limit the list of people who can be selected in the **Approvers** section. Thanks anyway Paddy!

Comment: You can set the approval group in configuration but the workflow initiator can always change it to someone else.